# Solving $Т(n)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{T(n-1)}+n^2}$ and $T(1) = 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations, fractions, telescopic-series

$$T(n) = \frac1{\frac1{T(n-1)}+n^2}$$

I did find $T(2) = \frac{1}{1+n^2}$, but I don't know how to proceed.

How do I go on from here? How can I find the solution? Thanks. :)

Comment: it is not clear what you meant

Comment: the way the question is written is weird, isn't $1/(1/y)=y$ ?

Comment: Please write your question in the description rather than just in the title.

Comment: Paul: I edited your title to what improve the formatting. Please confirm that this is what you meant to write.

Comment: I get $T(2)=1/5$ and $T(3)=5/46$. It's unclear to me if there's any pattern here.

Comment: $T(2) = \frac{1}{1+2^2} = \frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{T(n)}=\frac{1}{T(n-1)}+n^2$. Telescoping.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{1}{t_{n}}=\frac{1}{t_{n-1}}+n^2$$ and the rest is smooth I think:

$$\frac{1}{t_2}=\frac{1}{t_1}+2^2$$
$$\frac{1}{t_3}=\frac{1}{t_2}+3^2...$$
$$\frac{1}{t_n}=\frac{1}{t_{n-1}}+n^2.$$
A summing of these equalities gives:
$$\frac{1}{t_n}-\frac{1}{t_1}=2^2+3^2+...+n^2$$ or
$$\frac{1}{t_n}=1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2$$ or
$$\frac{1}{t_n}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$ 
The answer is:
$$t_n=\frac{6}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}$$

Comment: can you tell me how did you "telescope" this ?

Comment: @Paul Keseru See now, please.